# Зачем кэшировать данные сессии?

Tags: кэширование

Здравствуйте! Объясните, пожалуйста, для чего кэшируются данные сессии? Я понимаю, почему кэшируются некоторые запросы из бд, но вот зачем кэшировать данные сессии мне не понятно.

Comment: Сессии чего? Веб сессия? Сессия коннекта или что? Нужен контекст

Comment: и что вы под этим понимаете вообще

Comment: @Barmaley, речь о веб-сессии

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы понимать зачем кэшировать данные сессии, надо заглянуть под капот. Реализация сессий зависит от конкретного сервера, но в общем случае используются 2 подхода:

1. Под каждую сессию создается файл
2. Под каждую сессию создается запись в БД.

Например в любимом Java разработчиками сервере Tomcat реализованы оба механизма. В случае БД, табличка сессий выглядит приблизительно так:

```
create table tomcat_sessions (
  session_id     varchar(100) not null primary key,
  valid_session  char(1) not null,
  max_inactive   int not null,
  last_access    bigint not null,
  app_name       varchar(255),
  session_data   mediumblob, //переменные сессии здесь
  KEY kapp_name(app_name)
);
```

Для WebLogic выглядит так:

```
create table wl_servlet_sessions
  ( wl_id VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    wl_context_path VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    wl_is_new CHAR(1),
    wl_create_time NUMBER(20),
    wl_is_valid CHAR(1),
    wl_session_values LONG RAW, //переменные сессии здесь
    wl_access_time NUMBER(20),
    wl_max_inactive_interval INTEGER,
   PRIMARY KEY (wl_id, wl_context_path) );
```

Теперь сами себе ответьте на вопрос - если сессия это все равно запись в БД или еще того хуже внешний файл - надо его кэшировать или нет? Ответ мне кажется очевиден.

Answer (score 1):

Если какие-то сессионные переменные редко изменяются, но постоянно нужно их читать,то эти переменные иногда пишут в memcached для более быстрого доступа, но вообще этот подход не совсем верный и если неграмотно пользоваться, то вместо повышения производительности можно получить вполне ощутимые баги. Короче говоря - кэшируют в сессиях статичные данные, делают это аккуратно и под строгим контролем, делают для небольшого прироста в производительности.
Это конечно, если мы имеем в виду веб, хотелось бы немного больше конкретики в вопросе