# Кэширование сессии PHP

Tags: php, сессия, кэширование

Всем привет!
Как должен выглядеть хороший механизм кэширования сессии?
Проект: сайт для изучения городов РФ с отрисовкой карты, подсказками, статистикой изучения и т.д.(js, html, css). Вся информация находится в переменных объекта, который создаётся каждый раз при начале сессии, в переменные информация попадает из mysql.

Comment: тут по соседству вопрос был https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/738393/223826

Comment: Поставьте redis